# How to position content to align to responsive background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, positioning

I'm having trouble finding a way for the content to align to a specific point on the background image (not centering like in some solutions, but for example putting a H1 in a doorway (on the background image) 75% of the way along the photo so that when the responsive image / background is resized with the browser window / device, the H1 stays aligned to the exact same point on the image.

My pages have full screen responsive backgrounds using code similar to this found on sixrevisions.com:

```
body {
  /* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(images/background-photo-mobile-devices.jpg);

  /* Image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Image doesn't repeat */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Makes the image fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content height is greater than the image height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based on its container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Pick a solid background color that will be displayed while the background image is loading */
  background-color:#464646;

  /* SHORTHAND CSS NOTATION
   * background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
   */
}
```

Repeated searches have given many hundreds of non-relevant results, many people (eg: in the example above) solve this by centering text to the centered BG but that is side-stepping the issue of *positioning* the text so that when the window size changes the element's position stays aligned to some specific non-central point on the actual BG image.

I've discovered though trial and error that absolute position isn't working for me as I'm aligning the element to a point in the window which of course doesn't scale to any specific aspect ratio, whereas the BG image scales with the window somewhat but stays, rightly, at a specific aspect ratio.

My research has lead me to everywhere from 'responsive image mapping' JS solutions costing $100 to $200, to SVG image map solutions that seem to have potential difficulties with browser support etc. SVG image mapping interests me as it seems to be a way to provide anchors that align to the background on browser resize in the way described above.

http://demosthenes.info/blog/760/Create-A-Responsive-Imagemap-With-SVG

However that is a 'workaround' at best' All I need to position is text and simple anchors. If I cant solve it, I'll integrate text into the jpg and use svg image maps but his is not SEO friendly or good semantic design. Unfortunately I've been working on this for days and running out of time.

I found this relevant but not a solution:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Please let me know if I can help with any further clarification.

Comment: When you say absolute positioning did not work, how did you implement? Using % value or px or em?

Comment: tribe -content {
  position:absolute;
  /*vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;*/
  left:80%; top:73%;
}

As I said before, it was experimentation and guessing it's not the correct method as it is aligning to the window, not to the bg image which is fixed aspect

Comment: For example: Aligning the asterisk to the corner of the window with browser maximized: http://s1.postimg.org/b3ksj0pqn/SC_Max.jpg compared to the browser resized: http://s7.postimg.org/lyvdkbccb/SC_Resize.jpg

Comment: Seems like a thorough explanation but I'm still missing the point where you'd like the text to be *exactly*. On mobile only the center horizontal 300-400px might be visible while on widescreen it will be most of the vertical center (top and bottom disappearing). For the text to always stay in the same place, it would have to be inside the overlap of these extremes (so somewhere near the center in any case).

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm using media queries to take care of mobiles. I understand the outer edges of the desktop view are a no-go, I provided that last image in the reply to illustrate the answer a point of principle regarding tribe's question about usage of absolute positioning above; it is not the website just an illustration.  To clarify, I am using backgrounds covering the body via css, I am attempting to use CSS to align text to visual points on that image. For example in the photo linked above imagine an asterisk that stays in the window on the 2nd floor when you resize the browser

Comment: With the photos I was attempting to illustrate to tribe my reasoning on why that usage of absolute positioning was not applicable to what I was aiming to achieve, regardless of % value or other etc. I'm not saying there is not a solution involving absolute positioning, but I can't see how because having the (landscape) photograph fill the full screen is part of the premise of the design. I have considered whether achieving this full screen effect in a different way will open doors to the specific positioning I'm trying to achieve (ie: placing text on photographic content which covers browser)